# iOS: Zoom in to part of screen when using camera

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a `UIImagePickerController` to display video on screen. Is there a way to zoom a section of the live video?  E.g. a square section of the video?

If this is possible, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIImagePickerController class has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGAffineTransform cameraViewTransform
```

CGAffineTransform is documented [on this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html)

Keep in mind that this will only change the presentation of the camera input on screen. Cropping the output image is another matter, but the cameraTransform property can help you with that too.

Comment: How could I transform a small portion of it though, rather than the whole view?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.  If you're talking about showing part of the preview at 1x zoom and other parts at some other zoom, then you'll need to do much more than what UIImagePickerController can provide.  you'll have to look into AVFoundation, which is much more involved.